# How to show absolute div component over table and table has scroll

Tags: html, css

I have HTML table with scroll. On cell clicking, one custom component opens. Want to scroll that custom component also.

`jsfiddle Link:`: https://jsfiddle.net/rujz69nq/4/

The expected result is that custom component should open over the table. so when clicking on the last row it will not take extra space inside the table.

Any Help?

Comment: add overflow-y and a height to the custom component (floatContainer)

Comment: Thanks @Gerard. don't want scroll inside that custom component.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#test").click(
            function () {
                appendContainer();
            }            
        );
    });

function appendContainer() {
   $('#test').after("<div class='floatContainer'><div>test1</div></br><div>test2</div></br><div>test3</div></br><div>test4</div> </div>");
}

$(document).mouseup(function(e) 
{
    var container = $("#test");

    // if the target of the click isn't the container nor a descendant of the container
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        $('.floatContainer').hide();
    }
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
}
.positionRelative {
 position:relative; 
  background-color: yellow;
}
.floatContainer{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0 5px;
 height:60px; 
 overflow-y : scroll;
}
#container{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>Test table:</h2>
<div id="container">

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td class="positionRelative">
     <div>
         <div id="test"> test
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```